# Как сделать перенос первой строки и сокрытие всего остального в блоке?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

Кто знает, как сделать так, чтобы один раз строка в блоке переносилась, а всё что не влезло во вторую скрывалось за многоточие? Я с таким не сталкивался.

Уточнение: дизайн страницы гибкий. Соответственно, ширина ячейки меняется в зависимости от экрана. Есть мысль разбивать строку на клиенте используя JS

[image: Пример того, что нужно]

Comment: Решение нашёл. Но сайт не даёт его со смартфона нормально описать (код). Приеду к компу, выложу:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот что мне помогло в решении проблемы

http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl

Так как требовалось ещё и отцентровать блок по вертикали, вот, что я сделал.

HTML

```
<div class="table_row_item">
    <p>очень длинный текст, который надо перенести только один раз а в конце добавить многоточие, ага.</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table_row_item{
  border: solid black 1px;
  width: 150px;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
.table_row_item p{
  line-height: 10px;
  font-size: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 24px;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".table_row_item p").dotdotdot({
        callback: function(truncated){
            $(this).css("height", "auto");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот вариант [с англоязычного SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19049457/6263942).

Но это решение не поддерживается [Эксплорером и Файерфоксом](https://caniuse.com/#search=line-clamp).

```css
.two-lines-only {
  /* суть дела */
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 2;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  
  /* внешний вид */
  font-size: 2em;
  height: 3em;
  line-height: 1.5;
  width: 15em;
}
```

```html
<div class="two-lines-only">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ad dolores dicta maxime dolorum. Illo harum pariatur dolorem, provident laborum maiores praesentium molestiae culpa molestias officia veniam aut neque rerum dolores!
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Готовые JavaScript решения можно найти здесь: https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/

Comment: ссылки не приветствуются в качестве ответов на Stack Overfow

Comment: Хорошо, больше не буду так делать. Пусть пользователь остается вообще без решения :)